# ASP.Net Crafting Postback filter Data result

Tags: asp.net, autopostback

There's a private site (Energy Company - so I can't give details) that allows me to enter job numbers and check the current status if I give them an appropriate code for the job.  No user or pass required.  I'd like to make an automatic lookup in the datagrid I display on my own internal site for employees, by posting the code to the site and filtering the result.

I'm not exactly sure how to achieve this, but is it possible to manually craft a postback somehow to the external site and get the data filtered some way?  Or some other way?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite possible using [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) class. See this [tutorial](http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/dotnetwebrequest/dotnetwebrequest.htm) that describes how to do post using web request.